# Mock a private property

Tags: kotlin, mockk

Lets say we have a class like this:

```kotlin
class Whatever {
    private var something = false

    fun aMethod(): Int {
        return if( something ) {
            1
        } else {
            0
        }
    }
}
```

According to the [documentation](http://mockk.io/#private-functions-mocking--dynamic-calls), it looks like I should be able to do the following:

```kotlin
val classUnderTest = spyk(Whatever())

every { classUnderTest getProperty "something" } returns true

assertThat(classUnderTest.aMethod()).isEqualTo(1)
```

but instead I get the error: `io.mockk.MockKException: Missing calls inside every { ... } block`

I'm using mockk 1.8.5, kotlin 1.2.51

Comment: Currently, AFAIK, private [properties mocking are not yet supported](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/104). Check the linked issue for development of this behaviour

Comment: Why not using a getter? And mocking that.

Comment: @RafaelRuizMuñoz Don't want to expose or create a method just for testing

Comment: You can always use Super Reflect https://github.com/dpreussler/SuperReflect but for me, I don't know how, it didn't work when `testCoverage false`

Comment: @RafaelRuizMuñoz I've tried that and it does not work. Did you really tried that and was that working for you?

Comment: What exactly? Sorry it's an old question.

Answer (score 15):

Try to use answers instead of returns, like this:

```kotlin
val mock = spyk(MockCls(), recordPrivateCalls = true)

every { mock.property } answers { fieldValue }
every { mock getProperty "property" } propertyType Int::class answers { fieldValue + 6 }
every { mock setProperty "property" value any<Int>() } propertyType Int::class answers  { fieldValue += value }
every { mock.property = any() } propertyType Int::class answers {
  fieldValue = value + 1
} andThen {
  fieldValue = value - 1
}
```

Comment: I wonder if you could add some bit of explanation instead of just raw code? @Vova

Comment: his code is copied from this documentation https://mockk.io/

Answer (score 9):

You can use this small extension

```kotlin
fun Any.mockPrivateFields(vararg mocks: Any): Any {
    mocks.forEach { mock ->
        javaClass.declaredFields
                .filter { it.modifiers.and(Modifier.PRIVATE) > 0 || it.modifiers.and(Modifier.PROTECTED) > 0 }
                .firstOrNull { it.type == mock.javaClass}
                ?.also { it.isAccessible = true }
                ?.set(this, mock)
    }
    return this
}
```

it set the value of the first field of the same type passed as parameter, and can use multiple parameters, for instance:

```kotlin
myObject.mockPrivateFields(1, "hi!")
```

it will mock the first Int field found, and the first String field found.

This is only for private/protected fields.

You can modify it to support multiple fields of the same type. I didn't try it with generics but I guess it is not difficult to support it.

Comment: That's a very interesting way of doing it. I wonder why it's not part of MockK library with an annotation like `@Inject`

Comment: Superb answer, loved the hack, Solved my issue thanks you

Answer (score 4):

Elaborating on @Ignacio's answer:

```
inline fun <reified T> T.setPrivateField(field: String, value: Any): T  = apply {
    T::class.java.declaredFields
        .find { it.name == field}
        ?.also { it.isAccessible = true }
        ?.set(this, value)
}
```

Please note that this is technically not "mocking", you're actually setting the value in the instance, not intercepting the call to it.

Comment: perfect solution

Comment: this worked well enough for me needs.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This happens probably because [there is no getter/setter created](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/284#issuecomment-673780721) for your `something` property by the kotlin compiler.

What if you modified it to be like the following?

```
class Whatever {
    private val something
        get() = false

    fun aMethod(): Int {
        return if( something ) {
            1
        } else {
            0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change code for test is a wrong way

Comment: @Vova I hear what you're saying, but this is not always true. For example, one could argue that using dependency injection in our code _is_ a kind of "changing code for the sake of test(ability)".

Comment: I preferce the defenition dependency inversion, and using the DI in code is a kind of "common sence", and yes the DI has the positive side effect make code more testable